# Save only If changes made

Tags: vb.net

I have a Save button on my form to save data to DB, and I want to create a short code for "not saving anything" If user doesn't make changes, because saving involves a lot of Textbox/Combobox/DateTimePicker values.

In other words, is there any different solution that I could use, rather than like this:

```
 Using con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

            con.Open()

            Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

    Const SQL As String = "INSERT INTO MYTable (Field1,Field2,Field3 etc.) VALUES(: example1, : example2,: example3, etc.)"

                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(": example1",Textbox1.Text ))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(": example2",Textbox2.Text ))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(": example3",Textbox3.Text ))

                cmd.CommandText = SQL

                If Textbox1.text="" And Textbox2.text="" And Textbox3.text="" Then
                'Do nothing
                Else
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
                End if

            End Using

 End Using
```

Currently my code saves to DB, even If textboxes are blank - so probably empty strings are inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can simplyfy your code

```
If Textbox1.text="" And Textbox2.text="" And Textbox3.text="" Then
  'Do nothing
  Else
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
End if
```

```
If Not (Textbox1.text="" And Textbox2.text="" And Textbox3.text="") Then 
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
End if
```

or else

```
If Textbox1.text="" And Textbox2.text="" And Textbox3.text="" Then Exit Sub
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
```

---

One possible way to solve the rest are events + a flag. Give every control a listener (Textchanged, ValueChanged, ..depending on the control). If it fires set a Flag `Changes made` from default `False` to `True`

In the end Check if `Changes made` is `True` - If yes, then save it to DB.

Negative: If the User puts some text and removes it afterwards the flag will still be true - But you can see this behaviour in many applications.

Comment: Luke, can you show me some example of a flag ? Thanks for help !

Comment: An instance variable as a Boolean.

Comment: Aha, now I get you. Thanks for help again!